# Angularjs & Bootstrap - ng-repeat list filling

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Actually, I have an array of cars with several information. I want to display the data as following:

[image]

I am using ng-repeat with % operator to determine the position, but the problem is that $index % 4 == 0 is also true for $index % 2 == 0 if for example $index is 8 or 16..

How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `$index %4 == 0` is only true when you are in the 4th column. Why wouldn't you set column to `$index % 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap you just need to use bootstrap smartly to have this kind of view

This is how you can do it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" data-ng-repeat="car in cars">
        {{ car.name }}
    </div>
<div>
```